# List all Java Programming related courses that have a prerequisite

Tags: mysql

List all Java Programming related courses that have a prerequisite. List course no, description, prerequisite course no, prerequisite course description.

This is what I have so far and I included a picture of what it looks like.

```
SELECT COURSE_NO, DESCRIPTION, PREREQUISITE AS Prerequisite_course_no, description || ' ' || prerequisite AS Prerequisite_course_description
FROM course
WHERE description LIKE '%Java%' AND prerequisite IS NOT NULL;
```

The course table does not include a column called prerequisite course description. In the picture, you will see that the course description and prerequisite course number are displayed under prerequisite course description. I need prerequisite course description to display the correct course description that correlates with the prerequisite course number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vXUi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oXFa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding join operation using the same table twice can help. For example:

```
SELECT
    c.COURSE_NO,
    c.DESCRIPTION,
    c.PREREQUISITE AS Prerequisite_course_no,
    p.DESCRIPTION AS Prerequisite_course_description
FROM
    course c
JOIN
    course p
ON
    c.PREREQUISITE = p.COURSE_NO
WHERE
    c.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Java%'
    AND c.PREREQUISITE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: after trying this, i received an error of column ambiguously defined.